# Problem with decode tildes and special chars (PHP and MYSQL)

Tags: php, arrays, string, utf-8, utf8mb4

I need your help since I have a problem with accents and special characters. The thing is that I need to save an array in a database, so what I do is the following:

```
$serialized_array = json_encode($products, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

The problem is that then when I retrieve this array from the database and do json_decode($serialized_array); it doesn't return anything.

Instead, if I do:

```
$serialized_array = json_encode($products);
```

Then when I do decode it returns the array but with the wrong tildes:

["Platos del **d\u00eda"**,"Plato - Los dos juntos"]

Database connection:

```
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8mb4");
```

What can I do?

Thank you so much.

Comment: In what way are the accents wrong? can you post an example? One potential problem is that your database connection is not returning UTF-8 encoded text back to you. Can you include the database connection configuration int he question? Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: Just to be pedantic: "accent" represents the voice changes, and is not related to the drawings of the letters; those are "tildes".

Comment: 1-For example: ["Platos del d\u00eda","Plato - Los dos juntos"] instead ["Platos del día","Plato - Los dos juntos"].
2-And when encode with json_encode($products, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE), the tildes are correct in bbdd but when I select this data I can´t decode it.
3-I try the solution of this question and the error continues.
4-Yes, I have included the database connection configuration.

Comment: What is in `$products`?  Show it both as a string and as hex.

Comment: Hello, in $products there is strings, but the tildes are wrong. For example d\u00eda is the word día.